# Terminal name for Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to get the Hostname, Terminal of logged user in Oracle APEX.
Normally when using database is easy. 
e.g.

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL') FROM DUAL;
```

I have APEX running through tomcat 9.0 on linux server.
When I try it on APEX I get "unknown" value. When I try to get hostname

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','host') FROM DUAL;
```

I get the name of server that apex/ords/tomcat is running. I need to get the name of terminal of logged user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
begin  
    if( owa_util.get_cgi_env('X-Forwarded-For') is not null) then  
          htp.p('Client address is: ' || owa_util.get_cgi_env('X-Forwarded-For'));  
    else  
          htp.p('Remote address is: ' || owa_util.get_cgi_env('REMOTE_ADDR'));  
    end if;  
end;
```

from
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3994246?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I tried, It works, but it shows a IP address. The point is i need to get the terminal name, hostname of machine the user is using.

Comment: You can only get information that is submitted by the browser in the http-requests.